# Password Protect file or lock file from command line

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, terminal

I need to lock a file where if anyone tries to open it then it requires a password. I would like for even root to have to type in a password different from the root's password itself. I'm not sure this is possible but any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use for instance:

```
mcrypt filename
```

it will ask you for a passphrase. To decrypt the file you should use:

```
mcrypt -d filename.nc
```